# Send() Recv() in while loop

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a server/client chat program using sockets in c. Everything works well except of a print in the server side which prints the username that client send before the second recv(). But my print is after the second recv. It should First read the message from client and then print something like

> George: Hi

instead of

> George:
>
> George:Hi

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Server

```
recv(newSocket,name,sizeof(name),0);

while(1){
    recv(newSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    if (strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0){
       printf("%s logout\n",name);
       break;}
else
    printf("%s:%s",name,buffer);
}
```

Client

```
printf("Give a username");
scanf("%s",name);
send(clientSocket,name,sizeof(name),0);

while(1){
   fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
   send(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
   if (strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0)
      break;
}
```

Comment: You MUST completely and correctly handle the reult returned from system calls, especially recv().  You MUST ensure that C library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array get just that.  You MUST handle TCP received data as a byte stream, not as any kind of message larger than one byte.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit How can i do that sir?

Comment: man recv() would be a good start:)   It can return an int larger than zero, zero, or less than zero.  They all mean different things, and you must handle them all.

Comment: ThingyWosit is right. You need some state machine, which calls recv consecutively until a NUL is received (or until some other condition is fulfilled for a byte-level protocol). Can't show an example as I'm on mobile. I'm deleting my answer as it's invalid.

Comment: @nucleon can you provide me a code when its possible for you? Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's just about reading a complete zero-terminated string from the socket, have a look at @Andres Jaan Tack's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074824/reading-buffer-from-socket.

Comment: Looking at this might be more helpful even, granted you know some C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670807/sending-and-receiving-stdstring-over-socket. From my point of view, the socket API is a strange and complex low-level beast. It's quite hard to get a good grasp of the common idioms.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) @nucleon